# my rake task is continuously running in background due to which my server or console can't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, rails-console

I just run the rake task in my rails project and after complete my work, when i tried to run the console or terminal, it stuck, and when i stop it from running it gives me the error that there is an error in rake task. I think my rake task is still running in background.

I tried to kill the rake task but still this issue is there.

Comment: Hello Jahangeer,
Please share the definition of your rake task and the error message you are receiving. With the current details, this question is not answerable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.